# Determine opencore or stagefright framework for mediaplayer?

Tags: android, media-player

I need to determine if a mediaplayer is using the opencore media framework, so that I can disable seeking for my streams. The opencore framework appears to fail silently with seeking, which I am having a hard time believing they allowed into production, but that seems the case nonetheless.

I wish it were as simple as determining their SDK version, but droid phones that have api 8 seem to use opencore still, so doesn't seem to be a good option. Any ideas?

EDIT:

After the response from Jesus, I came up with this code. It seems to work well in my tests so far. If anybody doesn't think it is a sound method for seeking streams, let me know

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 8) //2.1 or earlier, opencore only, no stream seeking
        mStreamSeekable = false;
    else { // 2.2, check to see if stagefright enabled
        mStreamSeekable = false;
        try {
                FileInputStream buildIs = new FileInputStream(new File("/system/build.prop"));
                if (CloudUtils.inputStreamToString(buildIs).contains("media.stagefright.enable-player=true"))
                    mStreamSeekable = true;
            } catch (IOException e) { //problem finding build file
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hello, How to have CloudUtils class?

Comment: @AlexTran This should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/309424/read-convert-an-inputstream-to-a-string

Comment: Really sorry, I don't what do you mean what i will find from the link.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That method does not work on the Samsung Galaxy S, which says Stagefright is enabled but does not use it, at least not for streaming. A more secure check is to open a local socket and connect the MediaPlayer to it and see what it reports as User-Agent.

For instance, this is what I see on my Samsung Galaxy S and the 2.2 Emulator;

**Galaxy S:**
*User-Agent: CORE/6.506.4.1 OpenCORE/2.02 (Linux;Android 2.2)*

**Emulator:**
*User-Agent: stagefright/1.0 (Linux;Android 2.2)*

In one thread, do something like this;

```
    volatile int socketPort;

    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(0);
    socketPort = serverSocket.getLocalPort();

    Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();

    InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();

    byte [] temp = new byte [2048];     
    int bsize = -1;
    while(bsize <= 0) {
        bsize = is.read(temp);
    }
    String res = new String(temp, 0, bsize);

    if(res.indexOf("User-Agent: stagefright") >= 0) {
        // Found stagefright
    }

    socket.close();
    serverSocket.close();
```

And like this in another thread (makes the blocking accept() call above return);

```
    MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
    mp.setDataSource(String.format("http://127.0.0.1:%d/", socketPort));
    mp.prepare();
    mp.start();
```

Comment: this does not work for all phones for example htc phones has **User-Agent: HTC Streaming Player [operator-code] / 1.0 / htc_pyramid / 2.3.3** which does not have **stagefright** mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

With Android 2.3.5, now the media.stagefright.enable-player property does not exist in /system/build.prop

Answer (score 1):

To get that information you can read the file `/system/build.prop` of your device. In this file there is a parameter named `media.stagefright.enable-player`. If that parameter is set to true, then `stagefright` is active, otherwise your device is using `opencore`.

Comment: Looks promising, but Log.i(TAG,"Stagefright Enabled: " +System.getProperty("media.stagefright.enable-player")); //returns null on any device I test

Comment: That's true, sorry. Then you have to open the build.prop file and read the parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to detect if stagefright is enabled for streaming by searching for

```
media.stagefright.enable-http=true
```

instead of

```
media.stagefright.enable-player=true
```